# virtual WAN for devices in different LANs

Tags: lan

We have a number of linux devices, each living in its own LAN (each LAN with its own router, connected to internet). Each device can connect to internet but cannot be directly reached (i.e. no public ip address, no possibility to configure the router to forward incoming traffic). We are on public infrastructures using mainly IPv4.

We are looking for an (existing?) infrastructure/service, where:

- each device could be part of a virtual WAN, where each device gets a private ip address, possibly with a static assignment
- is it ok to share WAN ip addresses with other entities, we do not need to have a reserved WAN
- each private ip address can connect to the other ip addresses of the WAN
- cryptography/anonimization is not necessary
- decent latency and throughput: would like max 200-300 ms ping roundtrip, and would like at least 64-128 kbit/s on average
- WAN with multiple access points, if possible.
- ok to pay for the service, of course

We have already tested TOR: it fits quite well, in particular hidden services allow each device to be reached by the others; but the performance is really bad on average, with very high latency and very low bandwidth.

We have already tested OPENVPN in client/server mode: pretty good but we would need to mantain an openvpn server in the cloud. And we would get only a single entry point (unless we setup more servers...).

Any other ideas? 
Are there any usable virtual WAN infrastructures ready to use (beside tor and others, which unluckily are not so good for us in terms of performance)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided you can get at least one central system that is internet routable, you might try [tinc](https://www.tinc-vpn.org/).  It's a bare-bones minimalistic mesh-style VPN with very low overhead and reasonably good security.  Provided you're not constantly saturating the link, it's sufficiently light-weight to run with no issues on an AWS EC2 t2.micro instance or a 5$/month instance from most other providers, and it only needs an absolute bare minimum of other stuff on the system.  Latency can be as low as 1-2% higher than a direct link, and throughput is typically only a few percent at most below idealized for the path.

In my own experience, it's a bit more involved to set up than OpenVPN and has somewhat sub-par support for WIndows and Android, but provides a bit better performance for equivalent security and is somewhat more resilient to failures (if you've got multiple entry points and one goes down, stuff that was already connected to that one will failover to other ones automatically without any need for administrative intervention), and provides somewhat easier to use IPv6 support (both for the outter transport, and the WAN itself).

Comment: ok. We are looking into tinc and cjdns (which is linked to from tinc website).